# Let Excel prefetch the whole ragged hierarchy from SSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, hierarchy

I have the following ragged hierarchy:

[image: closed hierarchy]

You can see there is a plus sign in front of "Rent" however. Clicking on it, the hierarchy cannot be expanded:

[image: still closed although tried to open]

The hierarchy is saved as follows in the relational database:

[image: relational hierarchy]

I am using HideMemberIf OnlyChildWithParentName in the SSAS dimension settings.

How can make Excel to just show the expand sign, if it is actually possible? 
I have looked at the query beeing send with the SQL Server Profiler and can see the Excel just retrieves on level at a time. I want to force it to retrieve the whole hierarchy or at least the second level so that the user does not have non-working expand signs.

I know this does not appear with parent child hierarchies, however I have several constraints which do not allow me to use them.

Comment: if you create a custom set, using MDX, in Excel for that hierarchy what do you see ?

Comment: I need it as a hierarchy. With the set it would be flat. I just want to get rid of the + signs in my first image.

Answer (score 0):

If I understanding you correctly, you need also to set the `MDX Compatibility` in `Visual Studio(VS)` and `SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)`, so that you can get a placeholder value when browse cube. If I have anything misunderstand, please provide more informations.
`Ragged Hierarchies` are hand-in-hand with `HideMemberIf` and `MDX Compatibility`.

`MDX Compatibility` is one of Special-purpose parameters connection string properties when connecting to `Analysis Services`. The valid values include 0, 1, 2. 0 and 1 expose placeholder members; 2 does not. If this is empty, 0 is assumed.

Please see the links below:

[Ragged Hierarchies](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2009/11/11/ragged-hierarchies-hidememberif-and-mdx-compatibility/)
& 
[How to set MDX Compatibility](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6a824bfb-2ec7-4a8b-b3c0-4302214f3ade/how-to-set-the-mdx-compatibility2-in-visual-studio-and-ssms?forum=sqlanalysisservices)